# How to require user to login fb before accessing Facebook Canvas App webpapge directly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas, authentication, facebook-apps

I am new to Facebook App. I am developing my first Facebook Canvas App which links to a webpage hosting on my server.

I can now access the app by either:
(1) go to the Facebook App (http://apps.facebook.com/myappname), or
(2) directly access the webpage through URL(http://mywebsite.com/myapp).

I have set http://mywebsite.com/myapp as my canvas page in FB dashboard settings.

**I want to avoid (2) by requiring user to login FB first before they can access the page. I would like to know how can I do that?**

This may be a stupid question, but I have read the FB API documents (FB official guide talks a lot about setting custom login page) and searched through a lot of questions but they doesn't seem to fit what I need.

## UPDATE:

I have tried something like putting the following in my webpage:

```
<script> top.location.href = 'http://apps.facebook.com/myappname'</script>
```

In this case, if user access the page by (1), there's no problem. If user access the page by (2), user will be redirected to Facebook.

However in the client side we can still view the content of the webpage even if user is not logging in to Facebook. I want to achieve this in the server side.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved the problem by using examples from Facebook PHP SDK version 3.

https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php